# python ndarray multiply columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns that are json.
So for example,

```
df = A  B            C                 D
     1. 2. {b:1,c:2,d:{r:1,t:{y:0}}} {v:9}
```

I want to flatten it entirely, so every value in the json will be in a seperate columns, and the name will be the full path. So here the value 0 will be in the column:

`C_d_t_y`

What is the best way to do it, and without having to predefine the depth of the json or the fields?

Comment: Have you tried [pd.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) on that column?

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe contains only nested dictionaries (no lists), you can try:

```py
def get_values(df):
    def _parse(val, current_path):
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for k, v in val.items():
                yield from _parse(v, current_path + [k])
        else:
            yield "_".join(map(str, current_path)), val

    rows = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        tmp = {}
        for i in row.index:
            tmp.update(dict(_parse(row[i], [i])))
        rows.append(tmp)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows, index=df.index)


print(get_values(df))
```

Prints:

```
   A  B  C_b  C_c  C_d_r  C_d_t_y  D_v
0  1  2    1    2      1        0    9
```

Comment: It works well for the case of one column with nested dict but not in case of two. Any idea?

Comment: @okuoub Can you please edit your question and put there example of dataframe that's not working?